# Pointer to pointer to an array

Tags: c++, c, pointers, gstreamer, glib

**[This is a common C/C++ question, don't look on the Gst and G types]**

I have a pointer to an array with 2 items:

```
GstElement *videoconvert, *audioconvert;

GstElement *convert_array[2];
convert_array[0] = videoconvert;
convert_array[1] = audioconvert;
```

Which will pass in the callback function:

```
g_signal_connect(decodebin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), convert_array);
```

After "pad-added" signal my callback function will receive this pointer(convert_array) as a gpointer type:

```
void on_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data);
```

In this callback I need to extract my GstElements from the gpointer data, that's my unsuccessful attempt:

```
void on_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data) {
    GstElement videoelem = ((GstElement *)data)[0];
    GstElement audioelem = ((GstElement *)data)[1];
...
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: "pointer to an array with 2 items" is not the same as array of 2 pointers...

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, my fault. It's not seen but this is a pointer to an array with 2 pointers. UPD

Comment: The gpointer `data` argument in your callback (i.e. convert_array) is *not* a GstElement *.  It is a GstElement **.  Try `GstElement *videoelem = ((GstElement **)data)[0]`.  Better yet, for C++, use reinterpret_cast<GstElement**>(data) instead of the old c-style casts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`data` needs to be cast to `GstElement**`, not `GstElement*`. Remember that `convert_array` decays to `GstElement**`, not `GstElement*` when you use it in the line:

```
g_signal_connect(decodebin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(on_pad_added), convert_array);
```

Hence, you need to use:

```
void on_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data) {
    GstElement* videoelem = ((GstElement **)data)[0];
    GstElement* audioelem = ((GstElement **)data)[1];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> void on_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data) {
>   GstElement videoelem = ((GstElement *)data)[0];
>   GstElement audioelem = ((GstElement *)data)[1];
>   ...
> }
> ```

if your gpointer is actually same type as GstElement** then GstElements in the function should be pointer types:

```
void on_pad_added(GstElement *element, GstPad *pad, gpointer data) {
  GstElement* videoelem = ((GstElement **)data)[0];
  GstElement* audioelem = ((GstElement **)data)[1];
...
}
```